# Monostable "One shot" 555. Longer trigger than T (output pulse width) eliminator

Tags: 555, monostable, one-shot

It seemed to me that a classical "one shot" output will go low after a determined period set by T (Output Pulse Width), even if push button is held down. What I want to happen is, when the trigger is held, the output goes low after T expires. Now it will keep on going and never releases.

Description of the 1.st circuit:

1. When a momentary switch is only clicked, output will turn on LED for one second.
2. When a momentary switch is pressed and hold, output will still turn on LED and will keep it ON.

The goal is - 2.st circuit ?:

1. The same
2. Different! When a momentary switch is pressed and hold, output should only turn on for ONE second and then go LOW
3. And of course just the same if/when I repeat the procedure (re-click or re-press hold)

So nothing really complicated.

I tried to do something here, but I'm not sure. It makes sense?

[image]

Comment: Please explain in more detail what exactly you want this to do. Do you want it to latch on permanently if you hold the button long enough? That's possible, but you'll need more than a single 555 to do it; you could do it with two 555s and a comparator, I think.

Comment: I'm confused. You show pictures (incomplete detail there) and words, which I may understand (or not.) Are you looking for a ***long hold*** circuit? One that creates a pulse of a specific duration if and only if the button has been held longer than some specific time and where if the button is held longer still the pulse width remains the same and the button is then ignored until it is released later? Also, what happens if the button is only held for a short time?

Comment: @Hearth I'm sorry, I should explain it more clearly. So: Description of the 1.st circuit:

  1.  When a momentary switch is only clicked, output will turn on LED for one second.
   2. When a momentary switch is pressed and hold, output will still turn on LED and will keep it ON.

The goal is - 2.st circuit ?:

    1. The same
    2. Different! When a momentary switch is pressed and hold, output should only turn on for ONE second and then go LOW
    3. And of course just the same if/when I repeat the procedure (re-click or re-press hold)

Comment: I edit the main question for a better understanding.

Comment: @periblepsis 1. No, I want approx 1 sec. pulse to be generated to turn on a load. 2. Only if the button is held longer than 1 sec. should be ignored. 3. Yes, pulse should remain the same, but button release should not affect it 4. If button is held for a short time - the same, output should go high for 1 sec.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to do something here, but I'm not sure. It makes sense and it will work?

To me that seems something you can build out of a combination of at least two 555s, and an external logical gate.

> What will be approx. signal delay due to the 100nF cap?

That question makes no sense – that depends on how you design the rest.

> Someone might have a better solution?

Invest in (1€ of microcontroller + 1 decoupling capacitor for 5 ct) instead of in (2×75 ct for a CMOS 555 as you show (definitely don't go with the NE555 or other BJT 555s) + ca 12 external passives for ca 1€).

What you describe is a digital control problem, and microcontrollers are the ASICs for this kind of application. Your problem be solved by a microcontroller that gets woken by someone pressing the button and about 10 lines of code. Learning how to do that will open up way more opportunities than learning how to use a 50 years old chip.

Comment: 1. You think? Can you please check again, I now edited the question with more detailed instrucitons. 2. Doesn't it makes sense that 100nF charging time is affecting the trigger signal which will delay the output? 3. Thanks, I will definitely research this. However, I would still like to solve this particular case. There might be some more appropriate IC for it?

Comment: 1. yes 2. when you can tell me what exactly the source resistance is, and what the exact threshold voltage is, I can tell you how long a capacitor is going to charge until it crosses that threshold. 3. Yes, the appropriate IC is about any microcontroller. Seriously, the problem you describe is "I want to have a time-driven discrete state machine that I can configure". And that is **exactly** what a processor is. You describe a use case for a processor with a bit of memory for a simple configuration. That's 100% what a microcontroller is. You found the core niche of microcontrollers :)

Comment: I get you, although to learn & program a microcontroller does take time, which I at this moment don't have. Honestly, do you think that the circuit I've built won't work by the requirements? I really don't need it to be precise. Just to work and that's it.

Comment: what type of microntroller would you recommend for this case?

Comment: I think I would take care to use something that is very simple to use. I also assume you'd like something that comes in a DIP package, not in SMD?

Comment: I think for a beginner, I would recommend [micropython](https://micropython.org), and I'd say, go with a cheap board for a start! Interestingly, the cheap boards can often already do a lot. For example, [this one](https://www.tme.eu/de/en/details/esp32c3-devkitc-02/development-kits-others/espressif/esp32-c3-devkitc-02/) with buttons and an LED already, and if you enable that, also wireless communications. You can buy and use the small microcontroller module (the little square with the metal cap on top separately (2 to 4€), but then you'd have to attach a serial port to it yourself to program

Comment: … it (that's practically all that this board does: it has a USB plug, a USB-to-serial adapter, a bit of voltage regulation, so that you can run everything off the 5V from the USB plug if you want, buttons and an LED). You can then [download Micropython for that board](https://micropython.org/download/ESP32_GENERIC_C3/), and follow the [Getting Started/Tutorial guide](http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.20.0/esp32/quickref.html) of micropython.

Comment: I would preffer SMD as I would like to push it to the market one day. I would like to work on a chip that is suitable for PCB mass production.

Comment: @Domenico ah, that's actually the easier case! So, if you find any eval board, you can always buy the central chip on it separately, just as in case of the aforelinked board, you can buy the ESP32-C3 module, which is a SMD solderable component, from all distributors. For minimum cost, you would probably go for the **much** more anemic Attiny series of microcontrollers, which might really not be much fun to develop for. [Here's](https://www.tme.eu/de/en/details/attiny416-xnano/microchip-development-kits/microchip-technology/) an example evaluation board; the chip you'd later buy in quantities…

Comment: Thank You Marcus!

Comment: … is the small QFN square in the middle of the board. Once you have developed a program, you can either order the chips with the program "burned in" for you, or you program them during manufacturing. A solid amount more capable are ARM Cortex-M microcontrollers, of which there are literally thousands of different ones. You usually pick them by what peripherals you need – for example, if you build something for integration in a car, you'd want a CAN bus controller, and maybe an LCD controller, and a motor controller… these kinds of things. Eval boards for these are plenty, as well. I like the

Comment: … extremelly cheap larger [STM32 Nucleo](https://www.tme.eu/de/en/details/nucleo-f302r8/stm-development-kits/stmicroelectronics/) boards, because you can remove a few jumpers or break off the main part of the board, and they become fully functional programmers for in-circuit (read: in-manufacturing/production) programming, but the STM32 microcontrollers tend to be a few cent more expensive than the competition. The competion looks, for example [like this](https://ro.farnell.com/en-RO/microchip/atsamd10-xmini/eval-brd-samd10d14a-smart-mini/dp/2451533?st=atsamd10) (and the corresponding IC you'd

Comment: … buy en would be [exactly as on board](https://octopart.com/search?q=ATSAMD10D14A&currency=EUR&specs=0&distributor_id=3261&distributor_id=2402&distributor_id=1106&distributor_id=1532&distributor_id=819&distributor_id=15300&distributor_id=2628&distributor_id=459&distributor_id=4207) or [from the same family and potentially "better"](https://octopart.com/search?q=ATSAMD10*&currency=EUR&specs=0&distributor_id=3261&distributor_id=2402&distributor_id=1106&distributor_id=1532&distributor_id=819&distributor_id=15300&distributor_id=2628&distributor_id=459&distributor_id=4207&distributor_id=2401)

Comment: … or [from the same "larger family"](https://octopart.com/search?q=ATSAMD*&currency=EUR&specs=0&distributor_id=3261&distributor_id=2402&distributor_id=1106&distributor_id=1532&distributor_id=819&distributor_id=15300&distributor_id=2628&distributor_id=459&distributor_id=4207&distributor_id=2401&distributor_id=5192&manufacturer_id=252&sort=median_price_1000&sort-dir=asc). The board I linked to before is interesting, because as you can see, the cheaper of these "mid- to lower-range" microcontrollers from the ATSAMD\* series are ca 1.20€, whereas the ESP32 modules (not the whole eval boards) …

Comment: … might be less what you're looking for when you need tightly guaranteed safety controls, but at 2€ to 3€ including a million of peripherals that the < 2€ serieses of microcontrollers from ST or Microchip Inc don't even dream of having – including Bluetooth and Wifi connectivity, should it turn out you need that.

Comment: I'm currently deciding which microcontroller to order. Can you please elaborate slightly more on the last comment, as I don't 100% get it. Should I open a new thread?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be built with 2 transistors, a capacitor and a few resistors.
An example a bit down in the forums here (only a breadboard overview, note one superfluos resistor, and the rightmost transistor and LED is just for indication):
https://steamcommunity.com/app/2198800/discussions/0/3825284962828830989/

Another here with schematics:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pulse_circuits/pulse_circuits_monostable_multivibrator.htm

Comment: This is different. If you have only 2 transistor latch, you still don't have a timer. Anyway, I found that the scematics I did works properly. The only thing to play, was the "one shot" cap and resistors.

Comment: It will meet the requirement of your point #2 under the goal of the 2nd circuit (2st?), IE that the output will go low after a set period T, even if the button is held down.
But I might have misunderstood. Anyway, you've fixed it so that's good.

Comment: Thank you @wrOngplanet